# What is the view of Vedanta on rebirth after dying by suicide?

Tags: death, rebirth

Hindu Scriptures, Gita and Upanishads. Complete works of Vivekananda

Comment: There are many posts on suicide here you can use the search function.

Comment: I haven't read the Upanishads or Vivekananda's books. But i have gone through the Gita. The Gita usually remains silent on topics like Suicide ... But there's a book called Reincarnation by Swami Yogananda, you'll get it on Amazon. In that book its mentioned that those who commit suicide, ends up being aborted or miscarriaged in the next life ... Few years ago while surfing the web, i stumbled upon a website where some lady saint said that those who commit suicide, end up in a dark, sunless region. Most probably a kind of dark hell.